# Is there a sample project that illustrates using MediaPipe AAR on an ArFragment (sceneform)?

Tags: android, arcore, mediapipe

the idea is to track the users' face and augment it with 3d models. MediaPipe would run on the camera feed from arFragment to provide the info necessary to place a 3d model in the arFragment.
Is there a sample project that combines MediaPipe and ArFragment ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to use mediapipe's hand tracking in an ARCore app using Thomas Ghorisse's sceneform-android library to place 3D object on the user's face. I'm providing mediapipe with bitmpaps coming straight from the ARCore camera feed. Do you think this could be a good solution in any way?
Thank you.